# React Calculating View Width and Height for a swipeable View

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to calculate the View Width and height of a Swipeable View which has an Appbar and a Tab.
I have code that is working but I have used vh and vw parameters and am unsure of the support in iOS. Is there a better way to do this.

You can find the entire app here , can you suggest if there are any other ways in CSS to achieve the same.

Current Code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'
import Appbar from 'material-ui/AppBar'
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'material-ui/Tabs'
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views'
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton'
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add'

class Hello extends Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      tabSelected: 0,
      tabHeight:0
    }

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.tab)
    let height = this.tab.height
    this.setState({tabHeight: height})
    console.log(height)
  }
  handleChange = value => this.setState({tabSelected: value})

  render(){

  return(
    <div>
    <Appbar style={{
        backgroundColor: '#3e9bbe',
        position:'fixed',
        top:0,
        left:0,
        height:60
   }}
    title='Static Appbar'
    />
          <div>
            <Tabs
              ref={(tab) => this.tab = tab}
              style={{position:'fixed',
                      top:60,
                      left:0,
                      minheight:'100%',
                      minWidth:'100%'}}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.tabSelected} 
              >
              <Tab label="Info" value={0} />
              <Tab label="Questions" value={1} />
              <Tab label="Discussion" value={2} />
            </Tabs>
            </div>
            <div style={{position:'fixed', top:120, left:0, minWidth:'100%'}}>
            <SwipeableViews
              index={this.state.tabSelected}
              onChangeIndex={this.handleChange}>
              <div key='Tab1' style={{position:'relative', width:'100%', height:'calc(99vh - 60px - 48px)', overflow:'scroll'}}>
              <h1>TAB1</h1>
              <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tempus mi vitae iaculis iaculis. Aenean blandit maximus tortor, accumsan lobortis augue ultricies mattis. Cras in gravida lacus. Duis ac purus ex. Sed volutpat diam vitae velit vulputate ullamcorper. Donec interdum id augue quis suscipit. Pellentesque iaculis vulputate lectus, id porttitor mauris mollis in. Sed convallis sapien non eros eleifend condimentum. Etiam dictum vitae nibh sit amet varius. Nam eget interdum tellus. Donec dignissim, tortor id imperdiet ......             
              </p>
    <FloatingActionButton style={{position:'fixed', bottom:10, right:'calc(30px - 100vw * 1)'}} onClick={() => alert('Tab 2')}>
      <ContentAdd />
    </FloatingActionButton> 
              </div>
              <div key='Tab3' style={{position:'relative', width:'100%', height:500, overflow:'scroll'}}>
              <h1>TAB3</h1>
              <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tempus mi vitae iaculis iaculis. Aenean blandit maximus tortor, accumsan lobortis augue ultricies mattis. Cras in gravida lacus. Duis ac purus ex. Sed volutpat diam vitae velit vulputate ullamcorper. Donec interdum id augue quis suscipit. Pellentesque iaculis vulputate lectus, id porttitor mauris mollis in. Sed convallis sapien non eros eleifend condimentum. Etiam dictum vitae nibh sit amet varius. Nam eget interdum tellus. Donec dignissim, tortor id imperdiet egestas, velit lorem interdum purus, nec ultrices ante eros non ligula.
{+ More}

              </p>
    <FloatingActionButton style={{position:'fixed', bottom:10, right:'calc(30px - 100vw * 2'}} onClick={() => alert('Tab 3')}>
      <ContentAdd />
    </FloatingActionButton> 
              </div>                            
            </SwipeableViews>            
            </div>

    </div>
  )
  } 
}

export default Hello
```

**Example Application:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rmaterialui-playground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vw and vw has worked fine for me in iOS (browser) till now.
And if you want to try an alternative, maybe using window.innerHeight() may help.